# Удаление элементов внутри замкнутого контура в dxf файле на питон

Tags: python, cad, dxf

Нужно было написать прогу которая будет удалять все элементы внутри замкнутого контура в dxf файле, например маркировки или отверстия. Пытался реализовать это с помощью ezdxf, и ничего не работает.

```
import ezdxf

def remove_inside_contours(filename):
    doc = ezdxf.readfile(filename)
    model_space = doc.modelspace()

    for entity in model_space:
            if entity.dxftype() == 'POLYLINE' and entity.is_closed:
        # Удаление всех элементов внутри замкнутого контура
            inside_entities = [e for e in model_space if e.dxftype() != 'POLYLINE' and entity.is_inside((e.dxf.get_pos()*doc.dxf_units))]

        for inside_entity in inside_entities:
            inside_entity.delete()

doc.saveas(filename)

# Пример использования
remove_inside_contours('example.dxf')
```

если есть идеи, как нормально работать с CAD файлами, то буду очень признателен получить совет

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, форматирование кода. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks